# How to get fileName inside DoFn in apache beam while processing input file pattern

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am processing  large no of files which are inside one directory. I want to add fileName in metadata of processed data output. So that if something goes wrong while processing, we can check that what is input file for the processed record.

Is there a way i can get file name inside my DoFn. I am using apache beam 2.19.0 version

**Input file location - gs://bucket/extracted-files/***

Answer (score 1):

You can use transforms available in [FileIO class](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) for this purpose.

Specially you can use `FileIO.match()` followed by `FileIO.readMatches()` which results in a `PCollection` of `ReadableFile` objects. For each `ReadableFile` you have access to a byte channel for reading as well as a `Metadata` object that contains the name of the file.